# how to calculate the average value of transactions per account for each type of transaction in scala

Tags: scala

I have knowledge with respect to typical sql queries but I am facing the problem while writing in scala.

```
case class Transaction(
  transactionId: String,
  accountId: String,
  transactionDay: Int,
  category: String,
  transactionAmount: Double)
```

I created a list like this:

```
val transactions: List[Transaction] = transactionslines.map { line =>
  val split = line.split(',')
  Transaction(split(0), split(1), split(2).toInt, split(3), split(4).toDouble)
}.toList
```

Contents of the list `T0001,A27,1,GG,338.11`
Can anyone help me on how to calculate the average value of transactions per account for each type of transaction in scala?

Comment: by "type of transaction" you mean `Transaction.category`?

Comment: @TzachZohar yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` and then map the values into the average of amounts:

```
val result = transactions.groupBy(t => (t.accountId, t.category))
  .mapValues(_.map(_.transactionAmount))   // map lists of Transaction to lists of Doubles
  .mapValues(list => list.sum / list.size) // calculate average or each list
```

Comment: thank you can you help me in solving the below questions as well     
The maximum transaction value in the previous 5 days of transactions per account
• The average transaction value of the previous 5 days of transactions per account
• The total transaction value of transactions types “AA”, “CC” and “FF” in the previous 5 days per
account

Comment: No, not really - first, because SO is designed to answer one question at a time; Second - try using the answer (and the documentation about Scala collections) to solve these yourself; Most of these can be solved using similar operations (plus `filter`, `max`).